# Eureka form does not display

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

So I am rank beginner trying to use some example code from the GitHub page for Eureka. I am just trying to display my first form. Here is my code from ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Eureka



class myViewController: UIViewController {

    var form = Form.init();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        form +++ Section("Section1")
            <<< TextRow(){ row in
                row.title = "Text Row"
                row.placeholder = "Enter text here"

        }


    }
```

And here is the output on the simulator:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Jop.png)

What would I be doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Eureka's FormViewController instead of UIViewController as the base class for your view controller.  Then you can create your form like this and everything works smoothly:

```
import Eureka

class MyViewController: FormViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        form +++ Section("Section1")
            <<< TextRow() { row in
                row.title = "Text Row"
                row.placeholder = "Enter text here"
            }
        }
    }
}
```